# Filezilla Server not working on Windows Web Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, filezilla, windows-firewall

I've installed FileZilla Server on Windows Web Server 2008 R2. I've set up everything correctly on FileZilla and I can connect withing the server.

The problem
I cant connect to the server from other computer, I get the following error

> An error occured opening that folder on the FTP Server. Make sure you
>   have permission to access that folder.
>
> **Details** The operation timed out

**FileZilla server give this info**

> FileZilla Server version 0.9.41 beta
>
> Copyright 2001-2012 by Tim Kosse (tim.kosse@filezilla-project.org)
>
> Connecting to server...
>
> Connected, waiting for authentication
>
> Logged on
>
> (000030)2013/05/14 12:11:17 PM - (not logged in) (196.00.000.00)>
>   Connected, sending welcome message...
>
> (000030)2013/05/14 12:11:17 PM - (not logged in) (196.00.000.00)>
>   220-FileZilla Server version 0.9.41 beta
>
> (000030)2013/05/14 12:11:17 PM - (not logged in) (196.00.000.00)>
>   220-written by Tim Kosse (Tim.Kosse@gmx.de)
>
> (000030)2013/05/14 12:11:17 PM - (not logged in) (196.00.000.00)> 220
>   Please visit http://sourceforge.net/projects/filezilla/
>
> (000030)2013/05/14 12:11:17 PM - (not logged in) (196.00.000.00)> USER
>   Username
>
> (000030)2013/05/14 12:11:17 PM - (not logged in) (196.00.000.00)> 331
>   Password required for Username
>
> (000030)2013/05/14 12:11:17 PM - (not logged in) (196.00.000.00)> PASS
>
> ---
>
> (000030)2013/05/14 12:11:17 PM - Username (196.00.000.00)> 230 Logged
>   on
>
> (000030)2013/05/14 12:11:17 PM - Username (196.00.000.00)> opts utf8
>   on
>
> (000030)2013/05/14 12:11:17 PM - Username (196.00.000.00)> 200 UTF8
>   mode enabled
>
> (000030)2013/05/14 12:11:17 PM - Username (196.00.000.00)> PWD
>
> (000030)2013/05/14 12:11:17 PM - Username (196.00.000.00)> 257 "/" is
>   current directory.
>
> (000030)2013/05/14 12:11:17 PM - Username (196.00.000.00)> CWD /
>
> (000030)2013/05/14 12:11:17 PM - Username (196.00.000.00)> 250 CWD
>   successful. "/" is current directory.
>
> (000030)2013/05/14 12:11:17 PM - Username (196.00.000.00)> TYPE A
>
> (000030)2013/05/14 12:11:17 PM - Username (196.00.000.00)> 200 Type
>   set to A
>
> (000030)2013/05/14 12:11:17 PM - Username (196.00.000.00)> PASV
>
> (000030)2013/05/14 12:11:17 PM - Username (196.00.000.00)> 227
>   Entering Passive Mode (41,185,23,114,0,14)
>
> (000030)2013/05/14 12:13:17 PM - Username (196.00.000.00)> 421
>   Connection timed out.
>
> (000030)2013/05/14 12:13:17 PM - Username (196.00.000.00)>
>   disconnected.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could also be a couple of other issues

You need to allow Filezilla server.exe through the firewall (windows firewall advanced settings, allow program). I got it working with the passive port once I'd done this and opened up a couple of ports on the firewall also (21 definitely needs opening up)

This article might help

http://huberyy.wordpress.com/2012/08/03/set-up-a-ftp-server-in-windows-azure-virtual-machine-with-filezilla-no-coding/

Just ignore the bits about Azure endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

i would venture a guess and say the passive ports are blocked by a firewall etc..

in settings (filezilla server) go to passive mode and try entering the IP address of the server under "use the following IP" (this made a difference on my install - left the rest blank)

when i tried changing the port on the server to somehting other than 22 i had the hosting company open the new port to xyz for me but i ran into the same issues you are.. turns out its the passive port thats the issue.. resorted to just slug it out on port 22 instead.